# How to Change file name in a previous commit

Tags: git

I have done five commits and didn't push yet , and i discovered that i have a mistake  in my first commit , so i want to change the file name in the first commit i tried .

```
git reset  --soft HEAD^
git reset HEAD path/to/file
git mv oldName NewName
git commit --amend
```

but this creates a new commit , How to change file name in a previous commit ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the commits are `A-B-C-D-E` and `A` is the first.

```
git reset A --hard
git mv oldName newName
git commit --amend --no-edit
git cherry-pick A..E
```

The sha1 values of the 5 commits will be new. In fact 5 new commits are created and the branch moves away from the old `E` and points to the new `E`. In case you forget what the old `E` is, you could run `git reflog` to find it out. Or you could just create a new branch on the old `E` beforehand and delete it after the job is done. When you know what the old `E` is, `git log E` tells what `ABCD` are.

If any of `BCDE` touch the file before it's renamed, you will encounter conflicts when you cherry-pick that commit. Suppose `B` and `D` touch the renamed file but `C` and `E` don't. Then run the following commands in stead of `git cherry-pick A..E`.

```
git format-patch -1 B
git format-patch -1 D
#Two *.patch files are created. 
#Open and edit the *.patch, change the oldName to the newName in them.
git am <edited-B.patch>
git cherry-pick C
git am <edited-D.patch>
git cherry-pick E
rm *.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git rebase -i HEAD^^` then `r` to rename the commit.

Answer (score 0):

the solution i tried and works :

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
git mv oldeNAme.ext NEWNAME.ext
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```